# Why might a Pi Zero connected by USB OTG seem to disappear from the local network?

Tags: networking, pi-zero

## The set-up

I set up a Pi Zero running Stretch Lite, and connected it via USB in OTG mode to a MacBook.

I successfully found it at `raspberrypi.local` from the Macintosh, was able to ssh in, install various packages and run a small Python application.

## The problem

While the application was running, it seems to have dropped off the network with a `broken pipe`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ packet_write_wait: Connection to fe80::a648:c9cc:e29b:761e%bridge100 port 22: Broken pipe
```

## Sequence of events

- MacBook: Internet Sharing was *on* (as it has been for weeks).
- Pi SD card was configured appropriately.
- I connected the Pi via USB to the MacBook.
- I immediately was able to `ssh pi@raspberrypi.local`.
- I don't know what IP address the Pi had (I think the Mac gave it a 192.168.2.x address), but it was able to reach the Internet.
- While on the Pi, I installed various packages using apt and pip.
- I connected the servos and started using my Python application I downloaded from GitHub.
- While executing the program, which was producing output in the terminal, the Pi appeared to lose all network connectivity to the MacBook.
- The Pi continued for several minutes more until the program finished running.
- While trying to reconnect, I could no longer resolve `raspberrypi.local` from the Macintosh.
- The output of `arp -a` showed no sign of it:

  ```
  ➜  ~ arp -a   
   dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.1) at c4:ea:1d:6c:bd:ae on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   danieles-mbp.lan (192.168.1.137) at b8:e8:56:34:97:12 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
   ? (192.168.1.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
   ? (224.0.0.251) at 1:0:5e:0:0:fb on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
   ? (224.6.7.8) at 1:0:5e:6:7:8 on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
   ? (239.255.255.250) at 1:0:5e:7f:ff:fa on en0 ifscope permanent [ethernet]
   broadcasthost (255.255.255.255) at ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff on en0 ifscope [ethernet]
  ```
- After rebooting the Pi by disconnecting the power, I was once again able to reach it at `raspberrypi.local`.
- However, the Pi now has a 169.254.x.x address and cannot resolve host names, nor can it reach remote IP addresses.
- The Macintosh Network system preferences shows an *RNDIS/Ethernet gadget* attached, on a 169.254.x.x (not the one of the Pi - this is the address of that interface of the Mac).

Comment: So far, I think it was a power issue. Since adding a PSU to the Pi, all has been well and I have not been able to reproduce the problem. Perhaps the MacBook was unable to supply enough clean power for three servo motors and a Pi.

Answer (score 0):

`169.254.x.x` is a [Link-local address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address)
 and indicates no ipv4 address has been assigned, and will not unless you explicitly assign one.

`macOS` (I presume you aren't using a Macintosh) will `ssh` over a Link-local address, although from the error message appears to be using ipv6

I routinely `ssh` from `macOS` to my Pi and "Broken pipes" and timeouts are normal after periods of inactivity. If this concerns you you could enable keep-alive messages from the Pi.

Eventually you should be able to connect after timeout, but I usually find starting a fresh terminal session on the Mac enables a new connection to be established.

Comment: Thanks, though this didn't seem to be a timeout. As noted in the question, networking broke - the Mac was no longer able to resolve the `raspberryi.local` address. And even after rebooting the Pi, the Pi is unable to pick up an IP address and reach Internet hosts - which *was* previously possible.

Comment: From your edit there seems to be some detail missing from your question. In general if the Mac has Internet Connection Sharing you can NOT access the Pi with `ssh` - if ICS is not on then you can't access the internet from the Pi.

Comment: Updated to include the full sequence of events. However, I did have both Internet sharing on, **and** was able to access the Pi with SSH (and have been able to in the past). I suspect the Mac has messed something up. @Milliways

Comment: Well - I don't know what the problem was, but I turned Internet sharing off and on again, deleted the *RNDIS/Ethernet gadget* interface in Network preferences, and rebooted the Pi - and it now once again has picked up the a 192.168.2.16 address and can network correctly.